# Run data folder of xampp server into Wamp server

Tags: mariadb

How to run data folder of xampp server into Wamp server. To retrieve all the databases that were running in xampp before getting crashed into wamp server. I just want to retrieve all the databses that were running earlier in xampp server.

I tried copying files mainly data folder (xampp/mysql/data) from xampp server to wamp server (wamp/bin/mysql/mysql8.0.27/data). But, when i tried to access it from my navicat. I couldn't find any tables/databases from that folder.

Comment: Xampp use mariadb, not mysql. Moving data files between various versions, let alone products is not a great idea as file formats could have changed. If your mariadb crashed, then try to teatore it to another mariadb of the same version that you were using. Umfortunayely, you are asking the wromg audience here as you need help from dbas, not from developers.